# Strong parameters permit Array of Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, strong-parameters

I have data I am trying to POST that looks like `{ foo: [[:bar, 1], [:baz, 0]] }`.

How do I permit that using [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters)? The closest I can get is

`params.permit(foo: [[]])` which returns `{"foo"=>[]}`

Comment: I can't find a reference now, but I have a recollection that foo: [][] will work?

Comment: params.permit(foo: [][])
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)

Comment: Don't you want params.permit(foo:[[][]])? Or you might want to try params.permit(food:[bar:[],baz:[]]) if nested.

Comment: The first one fails with the same error I posted above and the second one returns the same as I posted in the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maletor,

it seems to me that the strong parameters can't handle array of array.
I did read the [code of it in github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9ab2d030209d9608a6c866d83210f5b3b7d2319e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L327) and it deals with **Symbol, String and Hash**.

For this case you'll have to handle with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
def permitted_params
  result = params.require(:model).permit(:attributes).to_h # No array of arrays or hashes
  result[:model][:array_of_arrays] = params[:model][:array_of_arrays]
  result
end
```

One step further, say you have a `Model#json` and you want to store `model.json[:array_of_arrays] = [[]]`:

```
def permitted_params
  result = params.require(:model).permit(:attributes).to_h # No array of arrays or hashes
  result[:json] ||= {}
  result[:json].merge!(array_of_arrays: params[:model][:json][:array_of_arrays])
  result
end
```

Make sure you have permitted all your un-trusted params before you call `to_h`, and be careful what you merge in afterwards.